# Coffeescript loop over google place autocomplete

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript

I'm trying to integrate multiple Google Places autocomplete fields in the same page and I just can't figure out why this dummy code is working :

```
$ ->
  options = types: ["(cities)"]

  insts = []
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName('autocomplete_city')

  insts[0] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(elements[0], options)
  google.maps.event.addListener insts[0], "place_changed", ->
    place = this.getPlace()
    datas = place.geometry.location.lat()+"::"+place.geometry.location.lng()

    $(elements[0]).next('input.autocomplete_city_id').val(datas)


  insts[1] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(elements[1], options)
  google.maps.event.addListener insts[1], "place_changed", ->
    place = this.getPlace()
    datas = place.geometry.location.lat()+"::"+place.geometry.location.lng()

    $(elements[1]).next('input.autocomplete_city_id').val(datas)
```

While this looped version doesn't work :

```
$ ->
  options = types: ["(cities)"]

  insts = []
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName('autocomplete_city')

  i = 0
  for element in elements
    insts[i] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element, options)

    google.maps.event.addListener insts[i], "place_changed", ->
      place = this.getPlace()
      datas = place.geometry.location.lat()+"::"+place.geometry.location.lng()

      $(element).next('input.autocomplete_city_id').val(datas)

    i += 1
```

In this case, only the last 'autocomplete_city_id' is filled up with the autocomplete datas, even if you type in the first autocomplete input ( = the "element" variable for the reciever is always the last one in the array)

Aren't those two snippets exactly the same or am I missing some serious Javascript OOP principle ? Is it a Coffeescript trap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on CoffeeScript's website:

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the do keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

You could probably modify your code as this:

```
$ ->
  options = types: ["(cities)"]

  insts = []
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName('autocomplete_city')

  i = 0
  for element in elements
    do (element) ->
      insts[i] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element, options)

      google.maps.event.addListener insts[i], "place_changed", ->
        place = this.getPlace()
        datas = place.geometry.location.lat()+"::"+place.geometry.location.lng()

        $(element).next('input.autocomplete_city_id').val(datas)

      i += 1
```

Something else: `for` statements could be used like `for element, index`. You can then drop the `i = 0` and its increment.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that strange behavior can be caused by `push` method in compiled js.

I've refactored your code a little, and added `return` in the loop.

```
$ ->
  options = types: ["(cities)"]

  insts = []
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName('autocomplete_city')

  for element, i in elements
    insts[i] = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element, options)

    google.maps.event.addListener insts[i], "place_changed", ->
      place = @.getPlace()
      datas = "#{place.geometry.location.lat()}::#{place.geometry.location.lng()}"
      $(element).next('input.autocomplete_city_id').val(datas)
      return
    return
```

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks :-). Nonetheless, next answer by Franck pointed out the "cooffeescript way" to solve this.